# SignalR with MVC4, cannot push from action on controller

Tags: signalr

I have a MVC4 application setup to test SignalR push notification and which is not working. (I have tested the chat application on the MVC official site and its working perfectly, the problem is when i pushing a message from controller). Please someone help me on this.

(1) I have startup cs as follows,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

namespace MvcApplication3
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }

}
```

---

(2) Hub class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace MvcApplication3
{
    [HubName("notificationHub")]
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {

    }
}
```

---

(3) what im doing on controller is,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SendMessage("This should be displayed on client !!");
    return View();
}

private void SendMessage(string message)
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    context.Clients.All.viewMessage(message);
}
```

---

(4) Finally on the Index view,

```
<style type="text/css">
    #span-display
    {
        color: red;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>

<span id="span-display"></span>

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var notificationhub = $.connection.notificationHub;

            notificationhub.client.viewMessage = function (message) {

                $('#span-display').html(message);
            };

            $.connection.hub.start();

        });

    </script>
}
```

please do help me guys , im on a deadline and couldn't solve this out. Please excuse me if this is a simple thing but im new to this technology.

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it is not working"?

Comment: that means the message is not displayed as i expected on the span :-(

Comment: does `message` contains something? Is `viewMessage` function being called?

Comment: i'm calling the method in controller in the Index action  SendMessage("This should be displayed on client !!");

Comment: pollirrata, i have placed a alert inside the method on the view but i has not been called at any given time though the debugger hits on the controller.

Comment: The problem is when directly calling it from the controller, when i define a method in the Hub class and call it from the hub.start().done() it will get called. Ex: $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   notificationhub.server.sendMessage("Hello world");
});

Comment: I found the root cause, anyway thank you guys for your help. It was because when i calling from the controller action the view is going to initialize and then only the client method gets initialized but at that time server call is already made without the method at the client so i hope thats why it's not working. :D

Answer (score 0):

I tested with a code almost equal, and it works, the only diference I found was in the startup class, there I have as well:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalR_Example.Hubs.Startup))]
namespace SignalR_Example.Hubs
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Try using the first line changing my values with your values, other thing important is the JS, have you checked your browser console?, is there any error or something like that?